# Why won't mailto include link parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

When this code runs the alert box comes up with the link that includes &list=groceries and &email=tim@sitebuilt.net. When the mailto: fires and brings up the email window those parameters are missing and I can't figure out why. the length of the string doesn't seem to matter.

This code has all it needs to run. You can run it here: http://jsfiddle.net/mckennatim/rRerR/

```
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>My Title</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->       
        <div data-role="content">   
            <h3>Add List</h3> 
            <form>
                <div data-role="controlgroup"  id="addwhat">
                    <input type="email"  id="shemail" name="inp0" class="inp" />
                </div>  
                <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="aisubmit">
                    <input type="submit" data-theme="b" id="mailit" value="mail it"/>
                </div>                          
             </form> 
        </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
    <script>
        $('body').on('click', "#mailit", function (e) { 
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            repo = "Sebaza";
            list = "groceries";
            semail = $("#shemail").val();
            //(semail);
            urri ='mailto:'+ semail  + '?subject=share this list with me' + '&cc=' + semail + '&body=Hi, I think it would be cool if we shared this ' + list +' list on our phones. That way when either of us modified it we would see the update. http://10.0.1.18/webeshoppin/stuff2get/www/food2buy.html?repo=' + repo + '&list=' + list + '&email=' + semail  ;
            window.location = urri;
            alert('clicked ashare ' +urri);   
        });          
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Patrick is right. The extra URL parameters are concatenated to the overall mailto URL and are treated like undefined parts of the mailto protocol, so they just fall out. If you escape them like Patrick suggests then they will blend in and become part of the body parameter.

Comment: Doesn't say what email client you are using -- not all support those extra params (I know because the one I wrote doesn't.. I'll get around to adding that someday)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The '?' and '&' characters are being stripped out by the parser of the mailto link.

Those characters need to be encoded.  Try replacing with:

```
? = %3F
& = %26
```

so, that JS line would look like:

```
urri ='mailto:'+ semail  + '?subject=share this list with me' + '&cc=' + semail + '&body=Hi, I think it would be cool if we shared this ' + list +' list on our phones. That way when either of us modified it we would see the update. http://10.0.1.18/webeshoppin/stuff2get/www/food2buy.html%3Frepo=' + repo + '%26list=' + list + '%26email=' + semail;
```

Comment: This demo works (employing `window.open()`) without the encoding in Firefox using Gmail to send the email: http://jsfiddle.net/rRerR/4/

Comment: That's interesting as I've been messing with registry settings, using google notifier and still can't prevent windows live mail from opening. Alas I tried your cose and it still opened up windows mail